# What is the definition of ImageCorrelate?

Tags: image-processing

I do not understand how `ImageCorrelate` works. So I made a test below. Define

```
img1 = Image[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}] - 1/2
img1 // ImageData
img2 = Image[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}] - 1/2
img2 // ImageData
```

gives

[image]

then

```
ImageCorrelate[img1, img2] // ImageData
ImageCorrelate[img2, img1] // ImageData
```

gives

```
{{0., 0.}, {-1., -0.5}}
{{0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, -0.5}}
```

How to understand this result? I thought `ImageCorrelate[img1, img2]` would be somewhat symmetric with respect to `ImageCorrelate[img2, img1]`.

Comment: @Domen Thank you so much! This solves my headache : )

Comment: (Putting back my comment): I think it's the [padding](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCorrelate.html#1117230844) that bothers you. Use `ImageCorrelate[..., Padding -> 0]`, and you'll get the "same" results (ie. symmetric).